# Data overflow while comparing the values

Tags: c

I have a doubt from the below 2 code snippets.

I ran this code on 64-bit machine (x86_64-linux-gnu). I can see the value `Val` overflows when the data type is `unsigned integer`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    unsigned int Val = 0xFFFFFFFF-15, Val2 = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    if (Val+16 < Val2)
    {
        printf("Val is less than Val2\n");
    }
}
```

If the data type is `unsigned char` it does not overflow.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    unsigned char Val = 0xFF-15, Val2 = 0xFF;
    if (Val+16 < Val2)
    {
        printf("Val is less than Val2\n");
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

> 1. *Does the value `Val` get promoted to high data type when the data type is unsigned char?*
> 2. *If yes, why did not it get promoted from 32-bit to 64-bit `unsigned long`?*

Comment: This isn't the 90's - a return type on `main` is required nowadays.

Comment: When doing arithmetic, everything is promoted to `int` if can fit, or to `unsigned int` if cannot. The size of these types is specific to your compiler and you can easily find it out.

Answer (score 6):

The C11 standard says the following (C11 6.3.11p2.2):

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`; otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the integer promotions. **All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.**

Thus:

1. `unsigned char` will be promoted - however it is an implementation detail whether `int` can represent all values of `unsigned char` - so it might be promoted to an `unsigned int` on those platforms. Yours is not one of those platforms, thus your second comparison is `(int)Val + 16 < (int)Val2`.
2. as the last sentence of the quoted paragraph tells, an `unsigned int` is never promoted. Since the arithmetic is done on unsigned ints in the first fragment, the result of `0xFFFFFFFF - 15 + 16` is `0U` on a computer with 32-value-bit unsigned int.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the second case the numbers are promoted to `int`. If you modify your code thus:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char Val = 0xFF-15, Val2 = 0xFF;
    if ((unsigned char)(Val+16) < Val2)
    {
        printf("Val is less than Val2\n");
    }
}
```

You will get the behaviour you expect.